# "replacement has length zero" when exporting data frame to xlsx in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am trying to export a dataframe with `library(openxlsx)` and

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df), file = "df.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

but I get the following error:

> Error in x[is.na(x)] <- na.string : replacement has length zero

Comment: What does df look like?

Comment: It's a large matrix of 4958 elements

Comment: It's hard to say what exactly the issue is when we cannot see the df. This issue is usually caused because the content of a column is too complex to write to an xlsx file. You can also try write.xlsx2 to speed up the process when you have a large (perhaps in your case wide) df

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem in a data frame with numeric columns (at least intended to be numeric), but, in my case, I was using the related `openxlsx::writeData`.
The data frame was generated using `sapply`, with functions which could deliver errors because of the data. So, I coded to fill with `NA` when an error were generated. I ended up with `NaN` and `NA`s in the same column.

What worked for me is conducting the following treatment before `writeData`:

```
df[is.na(df)]<-''
```

so, for your problem, the following may work:

```
df[is.na(df)]<-''
openxlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df), file = "df.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```